# MVC 4 logout not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, form-authentication

I have logout action which makes logout and redirects to login page but when I close browser without logout and open again on logout it redirects directly to login action without accessing logout action

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration=0)]
    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();
        HttpContext.User = null;

        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);


        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        HttpCookie cookie3 = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
        cookie3.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie3);

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        return null;
    }
```

and here is my webconfig settings

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LoginPage" 
           defaultUrl="~/User/MyKids" 
           timeout="99999999" 
           slidingExpiration="true" /> 
</authentication>
```

Comment: and here is my webconfig settings
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LoginPage" defaultUrl="~/User/MyKids" timeout="99999999"       slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>

Comment: Please add that your question instead of as a comment

Comment: Please post the login code too.

Comment: You're opening the site at the 'logout' view?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "open again" but if you are trying to access a part of the system that requires a "logged in" user, then the system is detecting the fact that you do not have a valid authentication and it is redirecting you to the login page specified in your configuration. It will not try to log you out, just try to log you in. This is the normal behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior. I guess you use forms-authentication with session cookies. So, when you open the browser again and access the logout page, the forms-authentication-module detects, that no valid cookie is available and redirects you to the login page.

Set createPersistentCookie to true, to remember the user: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: you are correct but it deletes cookie even if its persistent when I close the browser

Comment: Are you sure, that your flag ist true? I would check the model binding. You can also post your login-code here.